# Setting a baseline grid

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to setup a baseline grid for my page, but when I set the font scale, the text doesn't fit with the baseline grid.

What I'm doing wrong? The problem is related with the font scale?

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3stut/

And here is the code:

HTML

```
<body>

  <h1>Your Name</h1>
  <h2>Your Name</h2>
  <h3>Your Name</h3>
  <h4>Your Name</h4>
  <h5>Your Name</h5>
  <h6>Your Name</h6>
  <p>Paragraph</p>

</body>
```

CSS

```
body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, fieldset, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
fieldset, img {
  border: 0;
}
address, caption, cite, dfn, th, var {
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: normal;
}
caption, th {
  text-align: left;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
}
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
}
abbr, acronym {
  border: 0;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,hgroup,ul,ol,dd,p,figure,pre,table,fieldset,hr,.header,.media,.island{
margin-bottom:1.5rem;
}


html {
  font:1em/1.5 Cambria, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  background: url(http://media.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/technical-type/img/css/grid.png) center -6px repeat-y #fff;
  color: #333;
  width: 940px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }

body {
  width: 460px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 72px;
 }

h1 {font-size:48px;}
h2 {font-size:30px;}
h3 {font-size:24px;}
h4 {font-size:21px;}
h5 {font-size:18px;}
h6 {font-size:16px;}
```

Comment: define "baseline grid". I don't really understand your problem. There is btw no use of using the head elements when you change the layout of it. You could simply use a paragraph or any other text element. I would suggest not to change to font-size as that is what those elements are defined with by default.

Comment: My goal is to have all the text sit in a baseline grid, like this:http://media.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/technical-type/img/full/10.jpg, http://media.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/technical-type/img/full/09.jpg, in order to give vertical rhythm to my text

Comment: Isn't the original layout used for this? http://jsfiddle.net/3stut/3/

Comment: If I remove the font scale, all the text fits in the baseline: http://jsfiddle.net/3stut/4/, but I need to have a font scale

Comment: You want every margin to be the same or when the text scales bigger the margin also goes bigger? http://jsfiddle.net/3stut/6/ or http://jsfiddle.net/3stut/7/

Comment: I want all the text to fit in the same baseline: http://media.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/accurate-alignment.jpg

Comment: I would position this with divs. use wrappers for a header, right and left side.

Comment: In this example: https://gallery.mailchimp.com/7e093c5cf4/images/mobile_grid.png, all the text sits in the grid and I think they don't use divs and wrappers

Answer (score 2):

If “baseline grid” means what it traditionally means in typography, then the code has really no attempt at setting things in a baseline grid. For such a grid, you would need to make sure that the total heights (including margins) of elements are multiples of the grid line height. Without styling, e.g. headings and images do not sit on a baseline grid.

For headings, assuming your px-based sizing approach and the CSS reset that sets margins to zero, the following would make headings satisfy the basic requirement:

```
* { font-size:16px; line-height: 18px; }
h1 {font-size:48px; line-height: 54px;}
h2 {font-size:30px; line-height: 36px; }
h3 {font-size:24px; line-height: 36px; }
h4 {font-size:21px; line-height: 36px; }
h5 {font-size:18px; }
h6 {font-size:16px; }
```

Here, all line heights are integral multiples of 18px. You can modify the approach by making line heights partly smaller (even down to each element’s font size or a little below) and adding e.g. top margin accordingly.

This does not make heading text baselines align with normal text baselines in another column. Such adjustment would hardly be possible with CSS, since the distance between the bottom of the font and the font baseline is not known. If you only play with one font, or a few fonts, an expect them to be available, you could fine-tune things (e.g., with relative positioning) to make the baselines match. But the main point is that normal text baselines match, and this can be achieved by setting heights of elements as outlined above.

Comment: So my code is right? (http://jsfiddle.net/3stut/) I used: html { font:1em/1.5 Cambria, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;} and h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,hgroup,ul,ol,dd,p,figure,pre,table,fieldset,hr,.header,.media,.island{ margin-bottom:1.5rem;} in order to have the line-height and the margin-bottom multiples of 16px

Comment: @user2473588, you have set `line-height` on the root element only. Other elements will thus inherit the declared value of `1.5`, which will then get multiplied by the font size of each element.

Comment: Thanks, so the line-height always need to be a multiple of 16px?

Comment: The *total height* of an element’s are (content + border + margin, with due consideration of collapsing margins) needs to be a multiple of the line grid height. So you can make the line height smaller than such a multiple, if you compensate for this using a suitable vertical margin. Line height just sets the minimum height of line boxes in the content.

Comment: So for example if the margin and border is 0, the font-size + the line-height needs to be a multiple of the line grid height? Or it's only necessary to have the line height as multiple?

Comment: If margin and border are 0, then the `line-height` needs to be a multiple. The `font-size` as such is not relevant (except that it affects the `line-height`, if the latter is not explicitly set).

Comment: Ok understood. Considering that I set a margin-bottom:1.5rem for all the elements (inspired in the recommendation of this article http://csswizardry.com/2012/06/single-direction-margin-declarations/), it's always necessary to use a multiple in the line-height?

Answer (score 1):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3stut/2/)**

**css**

```
h1 {font-size:48px; margin:0; padding:0;}
h2 {font-size:30px;  margin:0; padding:0;}
h3 {font-size:24px;  margin:0; padding:0;}
h4 {font-size:21px;  margin:0; padding:0;}
h5 {font-size:18px;  margin:0; padding:0;}
h6 {font-size:16px;  margin:0; padding:0;}
```

--

Like `this?`

**[demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/3stut/9/)**

---

**[demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/3stut/11/)**

---

**[demo3](http://jsfiddle.net/3stut/12/)**

**css**

```
h1{
font-size:30px;
}
```

Comment: The text isn't aligned with the baseline

Comment: The baseline of the text: http://media.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/accurate-alignment.jpg

Comment: @user2473588 see my answer in demo1 you want to like this?\

Comment: I want all the text to fit like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3stut/4/, but I need to scale the headings.

Comment: For example, in this image all the text sits in the baseline: https://gallery.mailchimp.com/7e093c5cf4/images/mobile_grid.png

Comment: I think that the description provided by Jukka K. Korpela is the right one